# is there a way to silence malloc failure printing an error message?

Tags: c

I currently have a function that will use up all possible space to be allocated with malloc. The problem is that malloc prints an annoying error message every time it fails:

> a.out(32685,0x7fff75399000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1048576) failed (error code=3)
>   *** error: can't allocate region securely
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

and whats worse is it prints it around 20 times before the function finally finishes...

Is there a way to stop this error message from showing?

**edit:**

if you are curious the function I am using to fail malloc looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void    breakmalloc(void)
{
    int *i;
    long long int n;

    n = 1;
    i = (int*)&n;
    while (n)
    {
        while (i)
        {
            i = malloc(n);
            if (i)
                n = n + n;
        }
        n = n / 2;
        i = (int*)&n;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about making your code to stop calling `malloc` when it starts to fail?

Comment: Let us see your code.   Looks like a run-time error when you call your a.out so you could try redirecting stderr like this  ./a.out  >/dev/null  2&>1

Comment: @kaylum> that would defeat the point. He apparently wants to allocate as much as he can. He grows his malloc calls exponentially, then reduces them again once he hits the limit. Btw Theo, if your goal is just to see how large you can grow the data segment, you could consider direct calls to [`sbrk()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk). Or directly reading the value with `getrlimit()` (with RLIMIT_DATA limit).

Comment: I ran the posted code on ubuntu linux 16.04, compiling with `gcc`.  It did not output any runtime messages.  It ran about 1 second, then exited.

Comment: Just as an FYI - this looks like a message from an Apple device.  The OP might want to give details on the system and maybe the toolchain and command line used to build the program. I'm not experienced with Apple environments, but a quick googling doesn't net any results about ways to silence the message (all the search results were about how to fix or troubleshoot the bug that is triggering the message).